# Sorting an array of strings loaded from a text file

Tags: c, file, sorting

I have problem to sort an array of string by length loaded from txt file.

So I read from the file line by line and put the strings into an array, after that I sort that array by the length of the string, but I get a strange output of the array stream.

The problem is that the program is sorting an array of strings, but one of the strings is pasted on top of another.

Example:

The data in the file I'm reading from:

```
X&Y
X|Y
!X
(X|Y)|Z
(X&Y)|Z
(X&Y)&Z
(X&Y)|Z&(A|B
((X|Y)|Z)&((A|B)|(C&D))
(X&Y)|(Z&(A|B))
(A|B)&(!C)
A|(B&(C&(D|E)))
((X|Y)|(Z&(A|B)))|((C&D)&(D|E))
(A|B)|(C&D)&(D|E)
!A&(B|C)
(A|B)|(C|D)&(D
```

Content of the array after sorting in ascending order:

```
!X
X|Y
X&Y
(X|Y)|Z
(X&Y)|Z
(X&Y)&Z
!A&(B|C)
(A|B)&(!C)
(X&Y)|Z&(A|B
(A|B)|(C|D)&(DA|(B&(C&(D|E))) //Here' is problem ! (A|B)|(C|D)&(D and A|(B&(C&(D|E))) are concatenated?
(X&Y)|(Z&(A|B))
(A|B)|(C&D)&(D|E)
((X|Y)|Z)&((A|B)|(C&D))
((X|Y)|(Z&(A|B)))|((C&D)&(D|E))
```

Here is the code:

```
//Sort function
void sort(char str[][MAXLEN], int number_of_elements) {
    int d, j;
    char temp[100];
    for (d = 0; d < number_of_elements - 1; d++) {
        for (j = 0; j < number_of_elements - d - 1; j++) {
            if (strlen(str[j]) < strlen(str[j + 1])) {
                strcpy(temp, str[j]);
                strcpy(str[j], str[j + 1]);
                strcpy(str[j + 1], temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    FILE *dat;
    int number_of_elements;
    char str[MAX][MAXLEN];
    int i = 0;
    dat = fopen("ulaz.txt", "r");
    if (dat == NULL) {
        printf("Error");
    }
    while (!feof(dat) && !ferror(dat)) {
        if (fgets(str[i], 100, dat) != NULL)
            i++;
    }

    number_of_elements = i;
    fclose(dat);
    
    sort(str, number_of_elements);
    
    for (int d = 0; d < i; d++) {
        printf("%s", str[d]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Works exactly as I would expect, after changing the comparison from a less-than to a greater-than.  https://replit.com/@robertwharvey/LowQuarterlyMemorypool#main.c

Comment: You don't have concatenate strings like me?

Comment: @user3121023 how to fix that? I still have the same problem...

Comment: Check your data file.  The one in the example I provided has a trailing newline after the last line.

Comment: To fix it, simply add a newline after the last line, if it is not there.

Comment: I agree with @user3121023 that it would be best to always remove the newline character after using `fgets`, if it exists. See this question for various ways to do that: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/12149471)

Comment: Of course, if you remove the newline character from the input, you will then have to add a newline character to the output, by changing the line `printf("%s", str[d]);` to `printf("%s\n", str[d]);`.

Answer (score 1):

Your observations is consistent with the last line of the source file having no trailing newline: `(A|B)|(C|D)&(D`

You can correct the problem by stripping the newline after `fgets()` and always appending one in the output phase.

Also make sure that the temporary array used for swapping the strings is long enough: instead of `100` bytes, it should have a length of `MAXLEN`. Also stop reading from the file when `i` reaches `MAX`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN  200
#define MAX     100

//Sort function by decreasing string lengths
void sort(char str[][MAXLEN], int number_of_elements) {
    int d, j;
    for (d = 0; d < number_of_elements - 1; d++) {
        for (j = 0; j < number_of_elements - d - 1; j++) {
            if (strlen(str[j]) < strlen(str[j + 1])) {
                char temp[MAXLEN];
                strcpy(temp, str[j]);
                strcpy(str[j], str[j + 1]);
                strcpy(str[j + 1], temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int number_of_elements;
    char str[MAX][MAXLEN];
    int i;
    FILE *dat = fopen("ulaz.txt", "r");
    if (dat == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s: %s\n", "ulaz.txt", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < MAX && fgets(str[i], MAXLEN, dat) != NULL; i++) {
        /* strip the trailing newline if any */
        str[i][strcspn(str[i], "\n")] = '\0';
    }

    number_of_elements = i;
    fclose(dat);
    
    sort(str, number_of_elements);
    
    for (int d = 0; d < number_of_elements; d++) {
        printf("%s\n", str[d]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```